# Widget/block code in product custom attribute not rendering at front-end magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, blocks, product-attribute, custom-attributes, widget

I have created custom attribute of Input Type "Text Area" with WYSIWYG option Enable.

[image]

After that add widget code in that product custom attribute input at store back-end.

[image]

Its showing same code instead of widget value at store front-end product detail page.
[image]

Code in template file.

```
<?php
$_product = $block->getProduct();
echo $_product->getTest();
```

**Please guide me, why widget/block code not rendering at front-end ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will return same data as that data needs to be filter to get actual html.
It's kind of same data as cms page or block have all textarea type attribute data needs to be filter to get actual rendered value.

So do one thing in layout, pass **viewmodel** argument inside your block for which you have that template.
Like this:

```
<arguments> <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Namespace\ModuleName\ViewModel\Product</argument> </arguments>
```

Create a class as specified in view model argument and inside class you need to use :

```
use Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider;
```

> **Then declare it in constructor**

And create a function to call from template and inside function use it like:

```
$this->filterProvider->getPageFilter()->filter($_product->getTest());
```

Then you can call your **viewModel** inside template like this:

```
$viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
```

And call your function from `$viewModel`.

For detail about **viewModel** you can check [here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Usage-of-viewModel-in-Blocks/td-p/71019)

**You can create an helper and call it directly from template same thing (as stated above for class) can be used in helper class as well.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using template file `"app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/description.phtml"` to show custom attribute value. According that template file i need to modified or override that block `"Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description"`? If yes, then i think its not easy option.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: updated solution working. But FYI "Method getResource is deprecated"

Comment: Thanks for information, I have again updated my answer. That you can do without override of block.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with Object Manager but its not recommended to use it directly but dependency injection instead

```
<?php
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$filterProvider = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider');
echo $filterProvider->getPageFilter()->filter($_product->getTest());
```